# Probabilities in the board game risk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> In Risk, if a player attacks another player they can roll up to 3 dice. The defending player can choose to roll either 1 or 2 dice in defence. Let's say that the attackers three dice are labelled $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$, and the defenders two dice are labelled $C_1$ and $C_2$. They are listed such that $B_{(1)}$≤ $B_{(2)}$≤ $B_{(3)}$ where  $B_{(3)}$ denotes the highest number of eyes of the three dices of the attacker, and that $C_{(1)}$≤ $C_{(2)}$ where $C_{(2)}$ denotes the highest number of eyes of the two dices of the defender.

I have found the probability function for the defenders highest dice roll, $C_{(2)}$ which is
$$P(J=k)=\frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{36} for all k = 1,2,3,4,5,6$$

And I have found the probability function for the attacker's highest dice, $B_{(3)}$ which is
$$P(J=k)=\frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3}{216} for all k = 1,2,3,4,5,6$$

I want to find the probability $P(B_{(3)}$>$C_{(2)}$) and $P(B_{(2)}$>$C_{(1)})$, the probability of the attackers highest dice being larger the defenders highest dice, and the probability of the attackers second highest dice being larger than the defenders second highest dice.

For the probability of $P(B_{(3)}$>$C_{(2)})$, I note A = attacker and D = Defender, so I find the P(A>D), and since the throws are independent I know I can multiply their respective probabilities, from which I take the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{6} \frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{36} \cdot \frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3}{216}  \\$$
$$ = \frac{107}{432}$$

Yet this possibility seem far too low, which means I must have made a mistake.

Comment: attacker’s second highest dice being larger than the defender’s *highest* or *second highest* dice? Your words and formula are different.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited it now. I have to find the probability of the attackers second highest dice being larger than the defenders second highest dice.

Comment: Did you mean $P(B_{(3)}>C_{(2)})$ by $P(B_{(3)}$>P$C_{(2)}$?

Comment: Yes it is edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the highest rolls.$$\sum_{k=1}^{6} \frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{36} \cdot \frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3}{216}$$ looks like a wrong formula. You want $A>D$, so the formula should look like

$$\sum_{k=2}^{6} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{n^2 - (n-1)^2}{36}\right) \cdot \frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3}{216}.$$

I’ll explain the formula. Let us assume that the Attacker rolled maximum number $k$ (note that $k\ge 2$ for a chance for the Defender to roll *strictly less*). Then the Defender can roll any number from $1$ to $k-1$. So we multiply the probability of $A=k$ to the sum of probabilities $D=1$, …, $D=k-1$.

It is equal to

$$\sum_{k=2}^{6} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}2n-1\right) \cdot \frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3}{6^5}=$$

$$=\sum_{k=2}^{6} (k-1)^2 \cdot \frac{k^3 - (k-1)^3}{6^5}=$$

$$=\frac{3667}{7776}\approx 0.4716.$$

Now about the second highest rolls. The probability function of $k$ being the second highest roll for the Attacker can be calculated as $$\frac{6(k-1)(6-k)+1+3(k-1)+3(6-k)}{216}.$$

The four summands in the numerator are for situations when, in order:

- highest, second and lowest rolls are all different;
- they are the same;
- highest and second are the same, lowest is smaller;
- lowest and second are the same, highest is greater.

After the simplification we get: $$\frac{-6k^2+42k-20}{216}.$$

The probability of the second roll for the Defender to be equal to $k$ is calculated the same way as for the highest roll, just because the second roll is the lowest roll, so the logic is literally the same: $$\frac{(6-k+1)^2-(6-k)^2}{36}=\frac{13-2k}{36}.$$

The probability of $B_{(2)}>C_{(1)}$ is then

$$\sum_{k=2}^{6} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{13-2n}{36}\right) \cdot \frac{-6k^2+42k-20}{216}= $$

$$= \sum_{k=2}^{6} \frac{13(k-1)-2(k-1)k/2}{36} \cdot \frac{-6k^2+42k-20}{216}= $$

$$= \sum_{k=2}^{6} \frac{(k-1)(13-k)(-3k^2+21k-10)}{36\cdot 108}= $$

$$=\frac{1181}{1944}\approx 0.6075.$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Can you explain why you two different sum signs, and where you got k-1 from at the top of the sum sign?

Comment: I edited the answer to add an explanation.

Comment: @MarkusAndeasen I edited to add the answer to the second question, about the second highest rolls.

Comment: Can you explain from where you derive the summands of the second highest dice for the defender? Where did you get (6-k+1)^2 and (6-k)^2 from?

Comment: I understand everything else perfectly, except for how the summands of the second dice roll was derived.

Comment: There are $6-k+1$ numbers equal to or greater than $k$. So there is $(6-k+1)^2$ such pairs. There are $6-k$ numbers strictly greater than $k$. Numbers of such pairs is $(6-k)^2$. The difference $(6-k+1)^2-(6-k)^2$ is the number of pairs where at least one number is $k$ and the other is at least $k$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I understand it now